# Using FirstOrDefault() in a Where() clause

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I've got a LINQ query that's returning no results when I know that it should be returning at least one. I'm building up the query dynamically. I looked at the result set in the debugger right before I get to the line that filters out all of the results and it contains hundreds of rows. After this line, it contains 0 when it really should contain at least one.

```
query = query.Where(x => 
    x.Lineages.FirstOrDefault().Sire.Contains(options.PedigreeContains));
```

'x' in this case represents an entity called 'Horse'. 'options.PedigreeContains' is just a string value. The Lineages table looks like this:

```
ID         HorseID         Sire       Dam        etc...
```

I can even pull up a Horse entity in the debugger (the one I know should be returned as a result), inspect the Lineages property and see it fully populated, including the Sire value that matches my search. So everything SEEMS like it should be working, except there's obviously some issue with the LINQ query that I'm using.

Does anyone see anything inherently wrong with what I'm doing that would cause this to filter out results that I know should be there?

**EDIT:** For clarification, it's a 1-to-1 relationship. I know the Lineages object exists, I know there's only one, and I know it matches. It's just for some reason it's returning zero results so I thought there might be a problem with the way I wrote the query. If that query should work the way it's written though (minus all of the extra "possibilities" if no lineages exist, more than one, etc) then it must be an issue somewhere else in my code.

Comment: I've added the [tag:linq-to-sql] tag based on your question and other tags, but please remove it if I interpreted something incorrectly

Comment: What exactly you want from `query`? Is this work for you? `query = query.Where(x => 
    x.Lineages.Any(l=>l.Sire.Contains(options.PedigreeContains)));
`

Comment: I'm not sure it this works.. but did you try: `query.Where(x=>x.Lineages).FirstOrDefault().Sire.Contains(options.PedigreeContains);` OR `query.Where(x=>x.Lineages).Sire.Contains(options.PedigreeContains).FirstOrDefault();` BTW... What *options.PedigreeConta‌​ins* does contains? is it the same as the Sire?

Answer (score 1):

What if `FirstOrDefault` returns the "Default"? You'll get a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: In production I'll add .Where( x=> x.Lineages.Any()) before it, but for now I'm just trying to solve the immediate issue and I know they all have valid Lineage objects attached to them.

Answer (score 1):

You are providing no means to order the `Lineages`, if the first one returned does not have the desired `Sire` containing `option.PedigreeContains`.  In such a case, the result set would be empty, regardless of the other `Sire`'s in the `Lineages`.

Comment: Regarding the questions clarification: for 1-1 relationship, consider `Lineages.SingleOrDefault()`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually answring your question: **No. There is nothing inherently wrong with your query.** It must be an issue somewhere else in your query construction, in the database structure or in your data.

When debugging, instead of enumerating and verifying the result count, copy the `query` expression value and look what the generated SQL looks like. You can do that before and after altering the `IQueryable query`. Other suggestions like @Jalalx use of .Any() to avoid what @John Saunders points out.

Comment: _"copy the query expression value and look what the generated SQL looks like..."_, Hmm.. I would like to know How can I see the generated SQL?

Comment: toggle Breakpoint in that line, right click on `query` -> `Copy Value`, that's your query. In any case you can also do `dbCtx.Log = new System.IO.StreamWriter("linq-to-sql.log") { AutoFlush = true };` if you also want the possible params (@p0, @p1, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

If you do FirstOrDefault() where you have it, aren't you taking the first of what could be many sires, so if a later one matches your where you won't find it?

```
query = query.Where(x => 
    x.Lineages.FirstOrDefault(lineage => lineage.Sire.Contains(options.PedigreeContains))).Sire;
```